# GraphQL/Prisma Client Server Error: Variable '$data' cannot be non input type 'LinkCreateInput!'. (line 1, column 18)

Tags: node.js, server, graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am following the How To GraphQL Node.js tutorial and I am at the part "Connecting Server and Database with Prisma Bindings". I think I have everything set up correctly according to the tutorial but when I try to execute a post mutation in the GraphQL Playground it throws this error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$data' cannot be non input type 'LinkCreateInput!'. (line 1, column 18):\nmutation ($data: LinkCreateInput!) {\n                 ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "post"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not even sure what I should be getting back, but when I do the "info" query I get back the info from my index.js file:  "data": {
    "info": "This is the API for the Hacker News clone!, Get Rigth Witcha, imma get ya !!"
  }

So, I know that the info query is working. When I try to do the Feed query I get back this error in the GraphQl playground:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field 'links' on type 'Query'. (line 2, column 3):\n  links {\n  ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "feed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So only the Info query is working and the others keep sending back an error. I am so lost and I really want to get more skill with GRaohQL. When I go to my Prisma Client I can't access my Service. They only let me look at the list of my servers. I have screenshots of the console but I do not have enough reputation to post them with this question.

I have tried going over each step and making sure my code is correct. I've also checked out the HowToGraphql git repository however they only have the completed server code present and I would like to build mine from the ground up so their code isn't much help. I'm not sure if the problem is with the Prisma Client or my code. Any feedback or assistance would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the link to the repository: 
https://github.com/thelovesmith/HckrNws-Cln-GrphQL-Srvr

Please help!!

src/index.js:

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')
const { prisma } = require('./generated/prisma-client/index')
// Revolvers
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        info: () =>  'This is the API for the Hacker News clone!, 
Get Rigth Witcha, imma get ya !!' ,
        feed: (root, args, context, info) => {
            return context.prisma.links()
        }
    },
    Mutation: {
        post : (root, args, context) => {
            return context.prisma.createLink({
                url: args.url,
                description: args.description,
            })
        }
    },
}
//Server
const server = new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
    resolvers,
    //initializing context object that is being passed to each 
resolver 
    context: { prisma },
})
server.start(() => console.log('Server is running  on 
http://localhost:4000'))
```

schema.graphql:

```
type Query {
  info: String!
  feed: [Link!]!
}

type Mutation {
  post(url: String!, description: String!): Link!
}

type Link {
  id: ID!
  description: String!
  url: String!
}
```

prisma.yml:

```
# The HTTP endpoint for your Prisma API
#endpoint: ''
endpoint: https://us1.prisma.sh/avery-dante-hinds/hckrnws/dev

# Points to the file that contains your datamodel
datamodel: datamodel.prisma

# Specifies language & location for the generated Prisma client
generate:
  - generator: javascript-client
    output: ../src/generated/prisma-client
```

datamodel.prisma:

```
type Link { 
    id: ID! @ unique
    createdAt: DateTime!
    description: String!
    url: String!
}
```

## UPDATE

When I run Prisma Deploy I can an error message:

```
    ERROR: Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid input "{ 
 \n    id: ID! @ ", expected ImplementsInterfaces, DirectivesConst or 
FieldDefinitions (line 1, column 11):
type Link {
      ^

{
  "data": {
    "deploy": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 9
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "deploy"
      ],
      "code": 3017,
      "message": "Syntax error while parsing GraphQL query. Invalid 
input \"{ \\n    id: ID! @ \", expected ImplementsInterfaces, 
DirectivesConst or FieldDefinitions (line 1, column 11):\ntype Link { 
\n          ^",
      "requestId": "us1:cjr0vodzl2ykt0a71zuql5544"
    }
  ],
 "status": 200
}
```

Comment: Hey, I was just checking your project. It seems like there's a problem with your Prisma API. Did you run `prisma deploy` successfully?

Comment: Otherwise the code looks good 

Comment: @nburk HEy thank you! Originally when I ran prisma deploy it went through fine , but I just ran it again and got an error message

Comment: Can you post the error please?

Comment: @nburk I added it to the end of the question above. Under the Update subtitle. I realy appreciate your help

Comment: It seems like there's an issue with the `@unique` directive in your datamodel. There's a *space* between the `@` and `unique` that should not be there. Try to fix that and deploy again.

Comment: This is where the issue is: https://github.com/thelovesmith/HckrNws-Cln-GrphQL-Srvr/blob/master/prisma/datamodel.prisma#L2

Comment: oh wow smh such a silly mistake on my part. But yes It is working now and I have Prisma Deployed. Thank you @nburk !!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo in your datamodel, it should be `@unique` instead of `@ unique`.